# Can't use button on fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm trying to setOnClickListener for a button. When I execute the app i get NullPointerException on these button.

This is my fragment:

```
class EditProfileFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        edit_photo.setOnClickListener {  }


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false)
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.fragment.EditProfileFragment">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="48dp">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:text="@string/edit_profile"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="8dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I get the error from edit_profile button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move button click into  fragment's onViewCreated

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    edit_photo.setOnClickListener {  }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

let me first tell you the error 
oncreateview used to create view from layoutinflate so you must declare view firstly and then take an object from that view

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false)
var edit_photo = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_photo)        
edit_photo.setOnClickListener {  }
return view
}
```

here you tell os that i will created button instance from that view not before inflation